# Media files not being returned properly

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework

**models.py:**

```
   class FWVersion(models.Model):
        bin_file = models.FileField(upload_to='fW_media/bin/')
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

serializers.py:

```
class UploadFWSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FWVersion
        exclude = ('date_created',)

class GetFWSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FWVersion
        fields = ('name', 'bin_file',
        )
```

views.py:

```
class GetFWView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FWVersion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GetFWSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        lastest_fw = FWVersion.objects.first()
        return lastest_fw

class UploadFWView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UploadFWSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am using django-rest-framework to create APIs for uploading and retrieving the latest version of the `.bin` file. The APIs are working and I am able to upload a `.bin` file on the server. But when downloading the file again, the server returns the first uploaded file(the oldest one)even though the name, url are of the latest uploaded file. Sometimes rarely however, it returns the latest file. I have checked the server files, they are being uploaded properly. Is this because of some caching by Django or am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information. Where is the code for uploading and downloading these files?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code pretty clearly calls `first()` on the queryset in `GetFWView`, so I'm not sure why this behaviour surprises you. If you want to always return the latest one, then you should do that:

```
def get_object(self):
    lastest_fw = FWVersion.objects.latest('date_created')
```

As an aside, you shouldn't be using a ViewSet for that view; it only supports one operation, which is GET, so you should just use a [RetrieveAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview).

Comment: Even though I have made the changes you have suggested but it didn't help. The issue is, even if I manually enter the latest file URL, the file being returned by the server is not that file, instead, it returns an old file. I had done this kind of thing with image files earlier and never faced an issue but in this case I want to upload bin files.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_attachment_path(instance, filename):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    d = os.path.dirname(filename)
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f')[:-3]
    filename = os.path.join(d, current_time + ext)
    return 'fW_media/bin/{}'.format(filename)

class FWVersion(models.Model):
    bin_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_attachment_path)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class GetFWView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FWVersion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GetFWSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UploadFWSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
            return Response('upload success')
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)

    @list_route(methods=['GET'])
    def get_latest(self, request):
        lastest_fw = FWVersion.objects.latest('create_time')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(lastest_fw)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```